# How to call Web API from client using LINQ

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

we have API exposed which expose one entity i.e Advertisement and we have UI where we are calling this API to show the data . Currently , we are using using httpclient to call the API.

Now , we have requirement to show the list of the advertisement to show the advertisement posted by person whose first name starts with . API already have Iqueryableattribute.

So we should fire a query i.e http://XX.com/Api/Advertisements?$filter=startswith(Postedby, 'Alfr') eq true

Now i am building this query and getting the result. but what i want is flexible way to get this query automatically when i write a linq query i.e instead of building this query . is there any easy way to get the query like

from S in Advertisements
where S.PostedBY.StartsWith("Alfr")

This should get converted to required web api query. This way i will always have the flexibility

Please let me know your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at this article :

[Getting started with ASP.NET Web API 2.2 for OData v4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx)

Odata provides the mechanisms you're looking for :

[OData URL Conventions](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/)